# Visual studio 2015 missing start menu icons Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We are currently trying to deploy Visual studio 2015 Professional across our school in a windows 8 domain environment. Visual studio installs fine but its shortcut are missing from the start menu. and the search feature does not find visual studio. The program can be ran directly.

I have found some of the shortcuts in: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio Tools" however these are only for the command prompt tools and not for visual studio itself.

Is there anywhere else the shortcuts may be?

Comment: FYI expected default location is: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2015.lnk`.

Comment: Just installed it on another machine to try - It isn't in there. Interestingly the icons appear on the start menu and then disappear after about a minute.

Comment: You say they are there and then they disappear? It looks like some other "program" is doing its work... Isn't there anything else on the machine what could potentially remove them? And what will happen if you re-create main icon with target `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`? Will it get deleted again? Isn't antivirus software reporting recent removal of any "threats"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Microsoft Visual Studio Community executable located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438064/where-is-the-microsoft-visual-studio-community-executable-located)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out our domain has a script that deletes any shortcuts not in a sub folder - That would explain why the shortcuts are disappearing!

We have added a line to our install script to place the shortcut in the sub directory.

Answer (score 21):

I found the same thing happened with my installation under Windows 7

Instead of the shortcuts being inside the **Visual Studio 2015** start menu programs directory, I found them one level up in the parent directory - somewhere I did *not* expect them to be.

Comment: This is by design: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/08/07/visual-studio-2015-faq.aspx#CantFindVSInStartMenu - "...you can find the application at the top of the "All Programs" list...The application icon will no longer be located in the Visual Studio 2015 folder."

Comment: That's confusing. I just wasted time by reinstalling 2015 thinking something must have gone wrong. I had no idea the shortcuts would be one level up.

Comment: Thank you, saved my time! I thought something wrong went with installation of VS 2015

Comment: Additionally, when I type "Visual Studio" in the search bar, the shortcut doesn't come up in the list.  This sounds stupid, but it really trips up people the first time they're using the application

Answer (score 0):

The installation move the shortcut for visual studio 2015 outside the 2015 folder to be consistent with other Microsoft applications.

Type: Windows key to use "Search for programs and files", type "Visual Studio"  to open VS quickly.

or

Type: Windows key , click All programs, then click "visual studio 2015"