# Where is the Microsoft Visual Studio Community executable located?

Tags: visual-studio

I just installed it but I don't know where it is. Can anyone help me? I've looked in a lot of places but I still don't know.

Comment: Why are you looking for it? Installation added shortcuts on your desktop/Start Menu. If you want to use it in a build script though, you should use environment variables and the build batches like `VsDevCmd.bat`

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017 doesn't add shortcut to the desktop and I can't find it under start menu either. The only way to easily find it would be to write `devenv` in start search.

Comment: It's a valid question because I have a similar situation where an over bearing policy on a work network means that the user has very little control over their PC, therefore to add shortcuts to applications requires to you manually create a shortcut thereby needing to know the location of an .exe

Answer (score 59):

Look for `devenv.exe`, it should be at:

**Visual Studio Community 2015**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
```

**Visual Studio Community 2017**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE
```

**Visual Studio Professional 2017**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE
```

Comment: Thanks! However I realise now that I should not have been looking for the .exe file, but just the regular devenv file. But thanks anyway!

Comment: True for VS14. But where is VS15? (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE`)

Comment: I have Visual Studio Community 2015 installed and it is still located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`.

Comment: True but VS2015 is VS14. VS15 is VS2017.

Comment: Just installed VS Community 2017 and you're right it is at the location you specified.

Answer (score 18):

For VS2019 it's now at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

Comment: This is the right answer as of today. Also for MS-VS 2017, just substitute 2019 with 2017.

Answer (score 4):

I would say instead of looking at a predefined location for the installation which might change in future what you should do is as follows -

1. Search for visual studio in apps search
2. Right click and select "Open file location"
3. Once you have this shortcut, Right click on it and select and open properties and see the target field. This is your executable path.

For me it is -

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Comment: The problem is that installations of some Visual Studio versions cannot be found in Search. I've experienced this. The only way to really find Visual Studio `.exe` is to open predefined install directory.

Answer (score 4):

For VS 2022 it's now at (Program Files not Program Files x86):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE
```

Comment: This should not be so hard every time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Due to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-the-visual-studio-command-line
Visual Studio location could be
`\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Version\Offering` or
`\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Version\Offering`
where `Offering` is one of `Enterprise, Professional or Community`, Version is `2019`, etc

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 we can find the executable file under the below folder. I installed in D:

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE
```

Comment: and the file name is devenv.exe

Answer (score -1):

For VS 2020

```
"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```